# Update MSSQL DB Changelog using Liquibase Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, liquibase

I'm currently working on project which is using Kubernetes pods to deploy applications on local machine. To avoid traffic on the Development server DB, I am migrating that process on local development environment. For this I am using Liquibase to allow DB changelogs to automatically apply once the kube pods are initialized.

I already have a mssql pod running on my cluster which consists of the target Database I want to update.

This is my docker file which contains the liquibase image, the credentials are same as my mssql pod.

```
FROM liquibase/liquibase
ENV URL=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=PlayerDB
ENV USERNAME=sa
ENV PASSWORD=pl@y123
ENV CHANGELOGFILE=changelog.xml
CMD ["sh", "-c", "docker-entrypoint.sh --url=${URL} --username=${USERNAME} --password=${PASSWORD} --classpath=/liquibase/changelog --changeLogFile=${CHANGELOGFILE} update"]
```

This is my changelog file which contains the sql statements I want to trigger on my DB inside mssql pod

change-map.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: player-changelog-v1
data:
  changelog.sql: |-
    --liquibase formatted sql

    --changeset play:1
    --Database: PlayerDB
    CREATE TABLE test_table (test_id INT, test_column VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY (test_id));
```

Finally I have created a job which intends to update the Database by creating the new table

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: liquibase-job-v1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: liquibase
          image: play/liquibase
          env:
            - name: URL
              value: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=PlayerDB
            - name: USERNAME
              value: sa
            - name: PASSWORD
              value: pl@y123
            - name: CHANGELOGFILE
              value: changelog.sql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-vol
              mountPath: /liquibase/changelog
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: config-vol
          configMap:
            name: player-changelog-v1
```

The pod runs and then terminates on it's own but the table is not getting created.

Comment: Can you show what error are you getting?

Comment: Are you able gather logs from liquibase?  if you run it with logLevel=DEBUG and pipe that to a file we can see what's going on.

Comment: I keep getting this error 

`Starting Liquibase
Liquibase Community 3.8.0 by Datical
Errors:
The option --url is required.
The option --changeLogFile is required.`

Even though I am passing both these params as default in Dockefile and also from my pod template.

Answer (score 0):

If you logs are giving out the `Starting Liquibase Liquibase Community 3.8.0 by Datical Errors: The option --url is required. The option --changeLogFile is required.` then why don't you define parameters in the commands as well? They are mandatory Liquibase parameters to run the liquibase updates